# ZF2 PaginationControl Disaply Wrong URL

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

When I Click - my index page - 
**localhost/gov_app/public/approval_allowances/institute/index**

It displays the Data Set with Pagination.If i click "<<" or ">>" then it goes to **localhost/gov_app/public/approval_allowances/?page=2**

Unfortuantely ZF2 Pagination Control Gives Wrong Links.Here is my Codes

**index.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator, 'Elastic', 'approval_allowances/institute/partial/paginator.phtml') ?>
 <?php
 // add at the end of the file after the table
 echo $this->paginationControl(
     // the paginator object
     $paginator,
     // the scrolling style
     'sliding',
     // the partial to use to render the control
     array('approval_allowances/institute/partial/paginator.phtml','Approval_allowances'),
     // the route to link to when a user clicks a control link
     array('route' => 'institute')


 );
 ?>
```

**module.config.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2014 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Approval_allowances\Controller\Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'institute' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/approval_allowances/institute',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Approval_allowances\Controller\Institute',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'allowance_approval' => array(
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/approval_allowances',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Approval_allowances\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'aliases' => array(
            'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern' => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Approval_allowances\Controller\Index' => 'Approval_allowances\Controller\IndexController',
            'Approval_allowances\Controller\Institute' => 'Approval_allowances\Controller\InstituteController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions' => true,
        'doctype' => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template' => 'error/404',
        'exception_template' => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'approval_allowances/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/approval_allowances/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your index.phtml file to include the index action along with the route. Like this:

```
<?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator, 'Elastic', 'approval_allowances/institute/partial/paginator.phtml') ?>

     <?php
     // add at the end of the file after the table
     echo $this->paginationControl(
         // the paginator object
         $paginator,
         // the scrolling style
         'sliding',
         // the partial to use to render the control
         array('approval_allowances/institute/partial/paginator.phtml','Approval_allowances'),
         // the route to link to when a user clicks a control link
         array('route' => 'institute'
               'options' => array(
                  'action' => 'index'
                )
             )
           );
```

Comment: now its ok.but,there is some thing wrong.when i click my pagination links.it doen't display my results .Eg: http://localhost/gov_app/public/approval_allowances/?page=2.when i put this URL .,then it shows my results set - http://localhost/gov_app/public/approval_allowances/institute?page=2

Comment: What does your controller look like? Is the pagination being setup in the index action of your controller? Move the pagination logic to the index action of your controller and then it will work.

Comment: my controller is InstititueController.if i change my pagianation control template.,then it will work.

Comment: <a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route); ?>?page=<?php echo $this->previous; ?>">